# PHP regexp parse avoiding substrings

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a simple Markdown parser to output HTML for pages that also use some LaTeX equations. For example, for italics :

```php
  // italic
  $content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(\*|_)(.+)\1/',
    function ($m) {
      return "<i>" . $m[2] . "</i>";
    },
    $content
  );
```

Unfortunately, a lot of Markdown formatting clashes with LaTeX symbols (and also with code blocks), so I need to escape the LaTeX sections first, and parse Markdown only outside of these sections. The LaTeX bits are delimited by `$` and `$$`, so it's easy to spot them :

```php
preg_match("/\$+(.*?)\$+/", $content)
```

For example, this is a sample of a such page :

```html
## Section title

Lorem ipsum *dolores* sic amet. $E = mc^2$, and since :

$$
\cos(3*\pi*\sqrt{2}) = \delta
$$
```

So… clash between italics and multiplication.

My first guess is I should split the content into 2 arrays : one containing the LaTeX bits with their index, and one containing the non-LaTeX bits located between the LaTeX ones, process the second array aside, and then merge them back together.

`preg_split()` breaks on said patterns and returns the intermediate substrings, but ditches the substrings matching the patterns. It seems it can be tweaked with a `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to return all substrings including the breaking points matching the regexp, but the documentation doesn't show the output data structure when this flag is used, so I don't get how to iterate on the output array and only work on the parts not matching the pattern.

What does this function output and/or is there a better/faster way to perform pattern detection outside of regions matching some other pattern ?

Comment: For those who are not familiar with what your starting LaTEX document might be, you should show sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be making the parts that start and end with only `$` on the same line not part of the match using SKIP FAIL.

Then capture either `*` or `_` in a capture group and use the backreference `\1` to match the same char without matching the same char in between.

```
^\$+(?:\R(?!\$+$).*)*\R\$+$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([*_])((?:(?!\1).)+)\1
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\$+` Match 1+ occurrences of `$`
- `(?:\R(?!\$+$).*)*` Match all lines that do not have only `$`
- `\R\$+$` Match a line with only `$`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` Skip what is currently matched
- `([*_])` Capture either `*` or `_` in **group 1**
- `((?:(?!\1).)+)` Repeat matching all chars other than what is captured
- `\1` Backreference to group 1, matching the same char as captured

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE5Evn/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/rSl2r)

Example

```
$content= <<<'DATA'
## Section title

Lorem ipsum *dolores* sic amet. $E = mc^2$, and since :

$$
\cos(3*\pi*\sqrt{2}) = \delta
$$
DATA;

$content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^\$+(?:\R(?!\$+$).*)*\R\$+$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([*_])((?:(?!\1).)+)\1/m',
    function ($m) {
        return "<i>" . $m[2] . "</i>";
    },
    $content
);

echo $content;
```

Output

```
## Section title

Lorem ipsum <i>dolores</i> sic amet. $E = mc^2$, and since :

$$
\cos(3*\pi*\sqrt{2}) = \delta
$$
```

I must note that getting markup with a regex can be brittle and have edge cases.

You might make the pattern more specific by for example asserting whitespace boundaries.

```
^\$+(?:\R(?!\$+$).*)*\R\$+$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!\S)([*_])((?:(?!\1).)+)\1(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lWm2W9/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really helpful !